# Add multiple markers address $.each from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm trying to add multiple markers using address, and I'm struggling for hours to fix it, my `JSON` have 4 address and only iterate the first one then stop, but it wont add any markers. Someone can point where I'm missing?

```
function successAvoid(data, textStatus) {
    var geocoder;
    var map;
    var myOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-page"), myOptions);
    $.each(data, function (i, x) {
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': x.address}, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[i].geometry.location
                });
            } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try inserting `return true` after the geocoder.geocode call. If it is returning false, it is probably canceling the each loop.

From jquery.com:

> We can break the `$.each()` loop at a particular iteration by making the callback
>       function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in
>       a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration.

Comment: Forget it, that was right, i made a mistake on my code, it wasn't looping.

Comment: @fsi If you would, please mark this as the correct answer.